# How to get a common coordinate from two different coordinates on Elliptic Curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, keys, discrete-logarithm, elliptic-curve-generation, arithmetic

I am trying to write a `SageMath` script that multiplies two coordinates on Elliptic Curves into one common coordinate.

[SageMath Elliptic curves over finite fields documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.html)

```
p = Number

M1 = EllipticCurve (GF (p), [0,7])

C1 = M1 ([x1, y1])
C2 = M1 ([x2, y2])
C3 = C1 * C2
```

Somewhere they wrote that using sets of the `SageMath` function it is possible to do this. *How to do it?*

Comment: Before computing something, one must have a clear picture of what it is. We can add two points on an Elliptic Curve. We can multiply a point on an Elliptic curve by an integer (that's mathematically defined by repeated addition, and well-defined since addition is associative). But there is no common definition of the multiplication of two points on an Elliptic Curve, unless we also mention a generator $G$, in which case we can define that $C_1=c_1⋅G$ and  $C_2=c_2⋅G$ implies by definition that $C_1*C_2=(c_1×c_2)⋅G$ where $×$ is modular multiplication modulo the order $n$ of $G$.

Comment: If you're trying to find an implementation of the elliptic curve group law in sagemath, it uses the "+" operator. In other words, `C3=C1+C2` will set `C3` equal to the combination of `C1` and `C2` under the elliptic curve group law.

Comment: @DanielS  
How do I write `" + "operator` and this whole formula in 
 `SageMath`?

Comment: For addition: `C3 = C1 + C2` this works since you defined C1 and C1 as points. For multiplication: Does this answer your question? [How do I multiply two points on an elliptic curve?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/how-do-i-multiply-two-points-on-an-elliptic-curve), If not, please indicate your actual aim.

Comment: You can always [edit] your document and comment below to get it reopened, assuming of course that there is then enough information to distinguish it from the other Q/A.